# Unit Testing w/ Sinon: How do I test a variable inside of a Callback?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I a doing unit test with Sinon to at least try to get something to pass and am out of luck. I wasn't able to find anything online.

I have 2 problems:

1) I am trying to get a simple response, but it fails saying `spy` is `false`. When I log it, it says it's `true`.

2) I want to test the template in the callback function is equal to 'New Title'. I am unable to figure how to pass req, res, and next into router.get

#### router.js

```
const express = require('express'), router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
var template = {
  title: req.title,
  item: req.item,
  description: 'N/A'
};
res.render('index', template);

module.exports = router;
});
```

#### router.spec.js

```
const router = require('./router');
var res = {};
var req = {
  title: 'New Title',
  item: 'Blank Item'
};
var template = {
  title: req.title,
  item: req.item,
  description: 'N/A'
};


it('1) should call the response', ()=>{
 var spy = sinon.spy(route, 'get');
 route.get('/', ()=>{});
 console.log(spy.calledOnce); // equals true
 assert(spy.calledOnce).toBeTruthy();
 spy.restore();
});

it('2) should return a status 200', ()=>{
 var stub = sinon.stub().yield([req, res, next]);
 route.get('/', stub); // main problem
 assert.equal(200, res.statusCode);
 stub.restore();
});
```

I want to access the route handler so I can do further testing. Where and how can I implement route handling in this situation?

Comment: You should read [API Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API_testing). This is outside the purview of unit tests. You'll need to write proper integration tests as suggested by @deerawan

Answer (score 1):

Express app for routing is usually best to test with integration testing not unit testing that you attempted to do. [Supertest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest) can be used as the library.

Another improvement that we can do is to separate the logic to generate template into another file. And for this service, we can make a unit test on it. Use [mocha](https://mochajs.org/) or [jest](https://jestjs.io/) can be the option.

Example:

```
const request = require('supertest');
const express = require('express');
const service = require('./service'); // our new service file
const app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  const template = service.getTemplate(req);
  res.render('index', template);
});

// integration test, ideally must be separated into a test file e.g. app-integration-test.js

request(app)
  .get('/')
  .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
  .expect('Content-Length', '15')
  .expect(200)
  .end(function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });


// service.js

function getTemplate(req, res) {
  return {
    title: req.title,
    item: req.item,
    description: 'N/A'
  };
}

// service-unit-test.js

describe('service test', function() {
  it('returns template correctly', function() {
    const req = {
      title: 'someone',
      item: 'my item',
    }
    const template = service.getTemplate(req);

    expect(template).to.eql({
      title: 'someone',
      item: 'my item',
      description: 'N/A'
    })
  })
})
```

Hope it helps!